# Rails: How to check if certain user has Ability using CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan

I know when you want to check the ability, you do

```
can :read, Project, id:3
```

However, what if I wanted to create a page that showed all the users that could read Project #3?

In that page, how would I show all the users that had :read access to the specific project?

Something like

```
 <% User.all.each do |u| %>
   <% if u can :read, Project, id:3 %>
     <%= u.name %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Does the code above not work?  If so, why not?  Do you get an error?  Is the result not as you expected?

Answer (score 3):

you can check with this:

```
Ability.new(u).can? :read, project
```

Answer (score 0):

Cancan has documentation for this: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities

Based on your example:

```
include CanCan::Ability
project = Project.find(3)
User.all.each do |u|
    if u.can? :read, project
      #print the user or something
    end
end
```

Comment: I read through the docs, but didn't see the "u.can?" syntax. I'll try this out. Thanks!

Comment: I dont think the "u.can?" syntax works. it gives me an error: undefined method can?

Comment: @kibaekr My apologies, typically when I do something like this I'm doing it within an abilities.rb file, which I always have the line: `include CanCan::Ability` -- you have to include that module in orer to use the `can?` method on a user object.  I have updated the code in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a wiki on this issue:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/ability-for-other-users

Comment: That wiki entry was last updated ~ 2 years ago.  The `CanCan` project now has the `Ability` module.  You can `include CanCan::Ability` to access those features.

Comment: @Ecnalyr I don't think this works - it worked when i followed the link I posted, but says "undefined method `can?' for #<User:0x007fc75d202e30>" when using your updated solution